# Web View justify text in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-webview

How do you create Web View with justified text in Xamarin.Android? I would like to show about 10 short paragraphs with bold, underlined and justified text in Web View control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy. Look at the following code.

This is how you create a new `WebView`

```
var webViewDsc = new WebView(this)
                    {
                        LayoutParameters =
                            new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent),
                        HorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false,
                        VerticalScrollBarEnabled = true,
                    };
```

Then you need to put a html content inside the `WebView`

```
 webViewDsc.LoadUrl(@"file:///android_asset/Html/...");
```

Now inside the html code justify your desired tag

```
<p style="text-align:justify">
  Hello!
</p>
```

Comment: In fact, I have XML layout with a WebView in which I want load custom data like this: `webView.LoadData(data, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");`